# Batch set copy to return error

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have copy command used in my batch/cmd script. When copy is being done is possible that file that is copied already exists in destination. When such situation occurs script is hanging. In such case I do not know that script failed. Is it possible to force copy to return and not copy error instead of waiting for reply?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier to overwrite or continue without overwriting instead of checking for halts?

Comment: and could you show your code?

Comment: You must also consider that you may not be able to overwrite the file, say if another program was using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to copy files without overwriting

You can do this with `/-Y` switch of copy command (will not copy files in sub-directories):

```
@echo off
pushd "c:\my_dir"
for %%a in (*) do (
  echo n|copy /-Y "%%~a" "C:\somewhere_else"
)
```

`echo n|copy /-y` cannot be used with wild cards and you should iterate files one by one. Have on mind that `/-Y` is mandatory.

Comment: What does pushd do in this context? What mean (*) in for loop?

Comment: @R.Nec `(*)` means all files in the current directory

Comment: `pushd` changes to the directory specified after pushing the current directory on to a stack.  Although this script doesn't, you can then use `popd` to return to where you were.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code my help is limited, but this should set you in the right direction.

To see if there was an error copying you could use:

```
If %errorlevel% = 0
```

If `%errorlevel%` does = 0 then the copy has completed successfully, if not there was an error.

To see if the file exitst or not use:

```
IF EXIST [filename] [command]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can force copy using /-Y switch to ask what to do if duplicate occurs. When I do not use this switch, file is overwritten. And the result I desire is to return error level<>0 when copy occurs duplicate. Currently (with switch /-Y) it hangs because waits for human answer. I want to always answer no if duplicate is found. I've coded checking errorlevel but it doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

when i run test.bat if field i want copy some file to certain location

```
if errorlevel 0 ( if NOT EXIST c:\duplicatefile ( echo F | xcopy c:\fileyouwant s:\newnameifyouwant ) )
```

my example

```
start c:\test.bat 
if errorlevel 0 ( if NOT EXIST c:\soheil.txt ( echo F | xcopy s:
\soheil.txt c:\soheil.txt ) )
```